# Can someone explain briefly what is an API Sandbox?

Tags: api

I recently met a phrase API Sandbox.

**Can someone explain briefly what is an API Sandbox?**

Where "API Sandbox" is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **sandbox** is a testing environment that isolates untested code changes and outright experimentation from the production environment or repository, in the context of software development including Web development and revision control.

Sandboxing protects "live" servers and their data, vetted source code distributions, and other collections of code, data and/or content, proprietary or public, from changes that could be damaging to a mission-critical system or which could simply be difficult to revert.